# How to make a function execute in every iteration of a foreach

Tags: c#, .net, loops, static

I have a static method in a class, that I call from another class in a foreach loop. The problem is the method is actually executed once. How to make it on every iteration?

EDIT: I updated full class B. The problem is Parts enumerable that is bound to my xaml ListBox is filled only with the last _bing.

**Class A:**

```
foreach (Bing bing in MyBingsCollection)
{
    MyViewModel.GetBingVar(bing);
}
```

**Class B:**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static Bing _bing;

    public MyViewModel()
    {

    }

    public static void GetBingVar(Bing bing) // EDIT
    {
        _bing = bing;
    }

    public IEnumerable Parts
    {
        get
        {
            if (null != _bing)
            {
                if (typeof(MyType1) == _bing.Item.GetType())
                {
                    ObservableCollection<MyType1> MyType1ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType1>();

                    MyType1ItemsCollection.Add(..);

                    return MyType1ItemsCollection;
                }
                else if (typeof(MyType2) == _bing.Item.GetType())
                {
                    ObservableCollection<MyType2> MyType2ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType2>();

                    MyType2ItemsCollection.Add(..);

                    return MyType2ItemsCollection;
                }
            }

            return new ObservableCollection<object>();
        }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Parts");
        }
    }

    #region Prop changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The only way `GetBingVar` is executed only once is if there's only one item in the collection. However, this loop makes no sense (only the last call does anything).

Comment: How do you reach this conclusion? How many Bing instances exists in your collection?

Comment: Assuming multiple items in your collection, you keep changing the value of the same instance.

Comment: shouldn't it be _bing = tts; also?

Comment: Mephy, thats what I mean. Only the last call does something..

Comment: What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: That function will be executed multiple times.  Put a breaking point in it, and you will see this. Perhaps opur problem is related to an incorrect implementation of the inotifypropertychanged interface?

Comment: @V.G. every call does something, it is just the next call always overwrites the previous one. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your new code makes no sense. You create a new ObservableCollection, then you call `.Add()` exactly once for this collection, then you return it. How could this collection ever contain more than one item?

Answer (score 1):

If `MyBingsCollection` has 1 item, `GetBingVar` will be called once. If it has more items, it will be called more times.

In any case, if `GetBingVar` overwrites the same field `_bing` every time it's called, it will *look* like it was called only once (and only for the last item) because every invocation undoes what the previous invocation did.

Comment: I think thats what happens. How to fix this problem.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve.